# Central Limit Theorem for functions of random variables

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

"An insurance company wishes to collect a yearly premium on life insurance policies issued to two groups. There are 1000 people in $X_1$ and they have a 0.01 chance of dying in the year, and there are 500 people in $X_2$ and they have a 0.03 chance of dying in the year. Benefitors in $X_1$ get 20 000 dollars and benefitors in $X_2$ get 10 000 dollars. What premium should be collected such that it is equal to the 90th percentile of the distribution of the payout?"

I set it up:
$$X_1\sim bin(1000,0.01)$$
$$X_2\sim bin(500,0.03)$$
$$Y = 20X_1+10X_2$$
where $Y$ is thus (in thousands of dollars) the total payout associated with each collection.

and we are looking for an $\alpha$ such that
$$P(Y \leq \alpha) = 0.9$$

We are to use the central limit theorem to approximate the solution. This is where I get slightly lost. I planned to use the normalization formula

$$W = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma}$$ since $$Y = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iX_i$$.

We can calculate $\mu_y$ as $$20E(X_1)+ 10E(X_2) = 20*10 = 10*15 = 350$$
and use $$\sigma_y^{2} = \sum_i a_{i}^{2} \sigma_{Xi}^{2} = 20^2(1000*0.01(1-0.01)) + 10^2(500*0.03(1-0.03)) = 5415$$

Now we have 
$$P \left( \frac{Y - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma} \leq \frac{\alpha - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma} \right) =$$
$$\phi \left( \frac{\alpha - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma} \right) = $$
$$ \phi \left( \frac{\alpha - 2*350}{\sqrt{2*5415}} \right) = $$
$$  0.9 = \phi(1.29) $$

Which gives us $\alpha = 6.75...$  which is obviously quite wrong. I think my mistake is in my original assumption, that we can apply CLT to $Y$ "as is", and that I am missing something in its implementation. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you wanted to use a normal approximation, then:

1. No, you could not have used the CLT since it specifies that each $X_i$ be
   independent and *identically* distributed. In your scenario, the random variables are not identically distributed.
2. That's ok! Even if the random variables are not $iid$, for "large" $n$, it can still provide a "reasonable" approximation. In your work, you gave
   $$
   \Phi \left( \frac{\alpha - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma} \right) = 
   \Phi \left( \frac{\alpha - 2\cdot 350}{\sqrt{2\cdot 5415}} \right) =
    0.9.$$
   I did not check that each value was correct, but  it follows from what you gave that
   $$\alpha = \Phi^{-1}(.9)\cdot \sqrt{2\cdot 5415}+2\cdot 350 = 833.3676.$$
   I think you made a small mistake somewhere.

Comment: I see. Unfortunantly, that isn't the correct answer either, implying that I made some other mistake in the calculations. (The answer is roughly 444.234 or something like that, I don't have the book around right now)

I also see what you mean, the CLT does require iid, which these do not have. So how exactly would we proceed in finding $P(Y \leq \alpha) = 0.9$ ?

Comment: 1. I would double check the setup. Since you made a mistake calculating $\alpha$, you might have made another mistake else where. I can't vouch for your work.

2. $X_1,X_2$ can be approximated using a Poisson distribution. If I remember correctly $Y$ follows approximately $\text{pois}(25)$. So you would have to manually find $\alpha$ such that $P(Y\leq \alpha) = .9$.

These are my guesses.

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that this thing was skewed to begin with, so normal approximation was not going to be good anyway, even if your work was correct.

Comment: My mistake, $Y$ does not follow $\text{pois}(25)$, $X_1+X_2$ does. But that is not what you have.